# OpenVZ + CentOS 6.0 + Home Network

Tags: centos, openvz

Setup a centos 6 server at home and installed openvz kernel and all working fine.

My only issue is routing IPs to the containers *(typing the different IPs in from another PC showed my default web server so I know it is working there)* - I have assigned `2 IPs` to the one `NIC` in `centos` but my problem has been routing that to the container on the `openvz` stack with that IP - could it be simple config I am missing?

any help would be appreciated

- 192.168.2.49 - actual server running openvz + centos stack
- 192.168.2.100 - should route to the openvz container on the server but is routing to the same place as main IP

**UPDATE**

ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1C:C0:94:33:28
          inet addr:192.168.2.49  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:c0ff:fe94:3328/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4926 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4822 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:577713 (564.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1767109 (1.6 MiB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d0300000-d0320000

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1C:C0:94:33:28
          inet addr:192.168.2.100  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Memory:d0300000-d0320000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:97 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5748 (5.6 KiB)  TX bytes:5748 (5.6 KiB)

venet0    Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/128 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:3478 (3.3 KiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

veth101.0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:51:10:37:76
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:51ff:fe10:3776/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

and vzlist -a output

```
      CTID      NPROC STATUS    IP_ADDR         HOSTNAME
       101         16 running   192.168.2.100   -
```

Comment: Have you ever heard of Proxmox? Probably make your life a lot easier. http://www.proxmox.com/products/proxmox-ve

Comment: yes I have heard of it but wanting to do it manually and learn it myself - thanks for link though will check it out if I loose my hair! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you have the following in the file /etc/sysctl.conf :

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.proxy_arp = 0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
```

Check also your firewall rules, you need to have this rule :

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Good luck !

Comment: got the first bit - will try the second now! thanks

Comment: tried that command and did nothing after restarting service - went to file and did not put anything in there so added it by hand it input section - did not work tried it then in forward section and did not work - any ideas? thanks

Comment: Are you using venet or veth interface on your conainers ?
Please also provide us the result of the commands : vzlist -a  and  ifconfig.

Comment: It's look like you have make a mixing between the configuration of a venet and a veth interface.
Try to delete the eth0:0 virtual interface and use only a venet interface on the container (if you don't need broadcast).

Comment: ye I have tried a few things and not cleaned up as they have not worked - will try your suggestion thanks

Comment: can you tell me where I would place -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE in my iptables file? after or before certain rules? thanks

Comment: finally got it working! had to remove the default iptables rule for forwarding on the main machine - is there a way to forward and not remove this line? is this safe? I would expect so for a home network? thanks

Comment: got it sorted so far now but in my container I cannot get an internet connection - any help? :)

Comment: all sorted now! i will update this question with further details of info I found to sort some other stuff also. thanks for all your help!